# How to sort table in ascending order first on change of sorting column using tablesorter in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

How to sort table in ascending order first on change of sorting column using tablesorter in jquery?

If I click the first column once it will sort in ascending order, then If I go to the second column and click it, it should sort in ascending order. If I click the column twice then only it should sort in descending order.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tablesorter code, each column has it's sort order stored in the header element. By default, the sort is set to ascending on first click, then descending on second.

I don't know which version of tablesorter you are using, but if you are using the original from tablesorter.com (v2.0.5), then there is a *global* option that isn't listed in the documentation ([see this post on missing docs](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html)) named `sortInitialOrder` which can be set to either `"asc"` or `"desc"` to change the sort direction on first click.

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), you can still use the global `sortInitialOrder` option or apply it to specific columns by using the [`headers` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#headers). Additionally, there is a [`sortRestart` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortrestart) which forces the first click on any column to always use the `sortInitialOrder` first.

Another option that might interest you is the [`sortReset` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortreset) which makes the third click on a header restore the table to its initial unsorted state.

Comment: I added sortInitialOrder=''asc" in tablesorter but didn't work.

Comment: That option is set when you initialize tablesorter: `$('table').tablesorter({ sortInitialOrder: 'asc' });`

Comment: Yeah I did the same but doesn't work. Also am using Tablesorter 2.05.

Comment: `"asc"` is the default setting ([ref](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter/blob/master/jquery.tablesorter.js#L117)).